# libvirt: understand the domain by newbie

Tags: virtualization, qemu, libvirt, hypervisor

[Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/goals.html) gives the definition of `domain`, i.e. it is an instance of OS running in VM. But then `virsh domcapabilities` reports the capabilities of this OS as well as underlying `hypervisor`, so `domain` definition is kind of blurred, it's on the boundary of virtualized OS and hypervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `domain` in `libvirt` jargon is a VM. In some other documents you can see the word *guest* as well. `virsh domcapabilities` tells you can features can be used for the virtual machine on that hypervisor.